# How to suppress the printed text when I set the ticks of an ax?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In `matplotlib`, when I set the ticks of an `ax`, there will always be some text being printed out before the figure in the output of a cell, for example

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,5))

x = np.linspace(0,10*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)

ax.plot(y)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x)))
ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(len(x)),rotation=45)
```

after I run the code (in a cell), there will be such output before the figure

```
[Text(0, 0, '0'),
 Text(0, 0, '1'),
 Text(0, 0, '2'),
 Text(0, 0, '3'),
 Text(0, 0, '4'),
 Text(0, 0, '5'),
 Text(0, 0, '6'),
 Text(0, 0, '7'),
 Text(0, 0, '8'),
 Text(0, 0, '9'),
 Text(0, 0, '10'),
...
```

How can I suppress this output?

Comment: Add a `;` to the end of the last line.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, thank you